# Add a newly created/custom component on the palette

Tags: eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I am wondering if it is possible to add a newly created diagram component on the palette.

I am adding components on the diagram programmatically (with a wizard to ask the user which variables he would like to add in/on the component). And i would like to give the user the possibility to make a similar component by dragging and dropping from the palette.

(say you created a component "wheel" with some variables, it would be nice to be able to create 4 of them without having to use the wizard every time)

Comment: A possible workaround: In your wizard, give the user the option to create *n* components of the same type with the same variables, elicitating this with an additional textfield or similar.